# HTC/Google Nexus 9 Camera Failure

Tags: android, camera, crash, firmware, cyanogenmod

I am using a Nexus 9 with the current Cyanogenmod nightly build (flounder). Since the beginning of the device usage, the camera did not work. All applications crashed when they tried to access the camera. 
I am wondering if the needed firmware is missing. Maybe someone who has also a Flounder device can check if my firmware of the /vendor directory is complete:

```
/vendor/firmware/ $ ls
bcm20795_firmware.ncd
bcm4350b1.hcd
bcm4350c0.hcd
fw_bcmdhd.bin
fw_bcmdhd_apsta.bin
maxim_fp35.bin
nvavp_aacdec_ucode.bin
nvavp_aud_ucode.bin
nvavp_mp3dec_ucode.bin
nvavp_os_0ff00000.bin
nvavp_os_8ff00000.bin
nvavp_os_eff00000.bin
nvavp_os_f7e00000.bin
nvavp_vid_ucode_alt.bin
rt5677_elf_vad
sar0_CY8C.img
sar1_CY8C.img
sensor_hub.img
synaptics.img
tegra13x
touch_fusion.cfg
```

Thank you in advance!

LT